# Django Generic ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have three models named company, admin and jobpost . Here Both company and admin can post the job. So i would like to implement generic foreignkey in post model .

```
class Admin(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Company(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class JobPost(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey()
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    post_by = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

here id of Admin is integer and id of Company is UUID.
Is it possible to implement a generic foreignkey in this case.

Comment: Yes, you can, as adding a foreign key from one of your own models to ContentType allows your model to effectively tie itself to another model class. Put content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) like this.

Comment: @Rajesh. here id is an integer and a uuid field, but object_id is a PositiveIntegerField.

Comment: Add  primary_key=True as attribute for both Model's id Fields

Comment: @rajesh did you get my question.here pk of admin model is an integer and pk of company model is a uuid. But here object_id is a positive integer field(as per django documentation), so will it be a problem